# Dictionary to string not being read back as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Since the Json And Pickle methods aren't working out, i've decided to save my dictionaries as strings, and that works, but they arent being read.

I.E

Dictionary

```
a={'name': 'joe'}
```

Save:

```
file = open("save.txt", "w")
file.write(str(a))
file.close()
```

And that works.
But my load method doesn't read it.

Load:

```
f = open("save.txt", "r")
a = f
f.close()
```

So, it just doesn't become f.
I really don't want to use json or pickle, is there any way I could get this method working?

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not actually reading anything from the file (the file is not its contents). Second, when you fix that, you're going to get a string and need to transform that into a dictonary.

Fortunately both are straightforward to address....

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("save.txt") as infile:
    data = literal_eval(infile.read())
```

Comment: It prints the variables inside of 'a' but doesn't recognize them when I try to use them

Comment: Well, how are you trying to ”use” them?

Comment: Well for 'a' inside the dictionary is an appended 'age': 24 but, if I use a['age']+2 a is not recognized, but it will print 'age': 22. Is this a string and integer conflict?